# MigLayout: push does not do what I expect

Tags: java, layout, push, miglayout

I have a very simple layout issue using [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). Here is a short SSCCE

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class LayoutDemo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, hidemode 2, debug", "", ""));

        final JLabel[] labels = {new JLabel("Area 1"), new JLabel("Area 2"), new JLabel("Area 3")};
        for (final JLabel l : labels) {
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBackground(new Color(new Random().nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
            l.setOpaque(true);
        }
        panel.add(labels[0], "w 200!");
        panel.add(labels[1], "spany 2, push, grow, wrap");
        panel.add(labels[2], "w 200!, grow, pushy");

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

The cell of *Area 1* uses up the same vertical space as *Area 3*. But I want *Area 3* to push *Area 1* away as much as possible. How can I do this? The only fixed length is the width of the left two labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to explain why the your code did not do what you
have expected and provide a simple correction to it.

Labels Area 1 and Area 2 share the same row. The `push`
constraint of the label Area 2 expands the current row
and column. And since the two labels share the same row, 
it affects also the label Area 1. Changing the `push` 
constraint of the label Area 2 to `pushx` fixes it. 
The label Area 3 is pushed vertically by its own
`pushy` constraint, and therefore, label Area 1 and
Area 2 have the same height.

The following code example creates the expected layout:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;



public class MigLayoutPushEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutPushEx() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Gaps");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 5"));

        final JLabel[] labels = {new JLabel("Area 1"), 
            new JLabel("Area 2"), new JLabel("Area 3")};

        for (final JLabel l : labels) {
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        }

        add(labels[0], "w 200");
        add(labels[1], "w 200, h 200, spany 2, pushx, grow, wrap");
        add(labels[2], "w 200, grow, pushy");

        pack();
    }    


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutPushEx ex = new MigLayoutPushEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

[image: Areas]

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification and the solution. I like your solution more than the previous one, so you get the accept.

Answer (score 1):

May not be of the best use, but if your using the Eclipse IDE, I'd highly recommend using the window builder plugin.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

You can easily modify a Mig layout (or any kind of layout) to do exactly what you require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not a big fan of graphical builders. I prefer to create my own code. But the builder you recommended looks nice.

Comment: No problem, as @PKopachevsky just suggested, maybe try to use a MigLayout constructor ... E.G 

frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[301px,grow}[53px][173px,grow][10px][118px,grow]", "[122.00px,grow][171px,grow][177px,grow]"));

Answer (score 1):

Specify *Row constraints* in MigLayout constructor.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0, hidemode 2, debug", "[][]", "[][grow,fill]"));
```

Comment: That's working perfectly, thanks. Although I don't really understand why my code doesn't. Can you explain that?

Comment: I'm not sure if "pushy" without size parameter force component to fill as much place as possible. Whitepaper(http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html) says nothing about it

Comment: Ok, I see. I usually use MigLayout only with component constraints. I guess I have to dive into the row/col constraints. :) Thank you very much.